# Cannot pull shelves from TFS server in IntelliJ 12.1.4

Tags: version-control, tfs, ide, intellij-idea, shelveset

I do not seem to be able to access/pull VCS shelve sets using IntelliJ with Team Foundation Server.

After reading the documentation on JetBrains, it explains that in the 'Changes' window I should be able to see 'Local | Repository | Incoming | Shelve' this last one is only present if I have any local shelves, otherwise it disappears.

Is there any way with IntelliJ to access others people uploaded shelves to TFS? A plugin you are aware of maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not supported, [vote for the feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65883).